# How to let the user select an image from any location using fileupload control for saving into databse

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I want the user to select any file from this location(C:\Users\Ramakrishnan\Desktop\New folder\001.jpg), however I dont know how to do. For to start with learning, I have hardcoded only one file name in this location i.e 001.jpg. I use a fileupload control

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
  FileStream FS = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Ramakrishnan\Desktop\New folder\001.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
}
```

And if possible, I wanna let the user change the entire location. I mean instead of the above hardcoded location, he should load image from anywhere. How to do please :(

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
string[] files;
files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\Ramakrishnan\Desktop\New folder", "*.jpg");
string file = "";
int count = files.Count();

if (count > 0) {
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
      file = files[0];
      FileStream FS = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
   }
}

if (count > 1) {
   if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
   {
      file = files[1];
      FileStream FS = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, your solution is fair, but the problem is it retrives all the files and loops that many times. I want, only say suppose if the user chooses 2nd file, it should retrieve and save only that. Any ideas please ?

Comment: @Divine, ohh I see. I've editted my answer :) I've made it from memory but it should be something like that.